# Opening Location with Maps and marker pin

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, mapkit, xcode7, ios9.1

I want to open my latitude and longitude values with modified markers and with details. So that I need to check if google map app installed I need to open with that else I will navigate into apple map.

Here I couldn't add custom pin with following code,

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"maps.apple.com/?z=12&q=%f,%f",[latitude floatValue],[longitude floatValue]]];

        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            NSLog(@"Google Maps app is not installed");
            //left as an exercise for the reader: open the Google Maps mobile website instead!
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:rdOfficeLocation addressDictionary:nil];

            MKMapItem *item = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];

            item.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[mDataArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"NAME"]];
            item.phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[mDataArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"DESTINATION"]];
            [item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];

        } else {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

        }
```

So please help me to add custom pin values for both apple and google maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at how to add a [custom marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker?hl=en) in the official documentation. However, this will only work for Google Maps and not Apple Maps (in which case you'll need a different library for it)